# change boot order using command line

Tags: windows, boot, bcdedit

I have Windows installed Surface Pro 6 and I am trying to change the boot order to boot first from USB and not from Windows without getting into the BIOS.

Windows 10 is in C:

Disk on key (WinPE Bootable USB drive) is on E:

How can I switch between them ? I saw something like

```
bcdedit /createstore bcd
bcdedit /import bcd
del bcd
bcdedit /create {bootmgr}
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device boot
bcdedit /timeout 10
bcdedit /create /d "USB" /application osloader
bcdedit /default {<GUID>}
bcdedit /set {default} device partition=e:
bcdedit /set {default} path  \Windows\system32\winload.efi
bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=e:
bcdedit /set {default} systemroot \Windows
bcdedit /set {default} detecthal yes
bcdedit /displayorder {default} /addlast
```

but it is not working. I get the message after restart on missing file winload.efi. can someone help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On power-on UEFI firmware enumerates connected devices and checks every device for EFI partition or FAT partition and boot application candidates on them.

Some entries appear permanently (e.g. boot application on EFI System partition on GPT disk attached)

[UEFI and CMS boot devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByaQs.png)

As can be seen in the image "EFI USB device" is listed permanently on a Dell laptop with UEFI firmware. This entry may not exist on a different brand laptop as the firmware start-up procedure may be implemented differently and list only really attached devices at boot time.

When booted to Windows 10 for example you could use the [BootNext tool](https://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html) to boot to any OS with boot entry in BCD or any bootable device attached (if CMS enabled, e.g. BIOS booting).

To be bootable in UEFI a USB device should be formatted with FAT32.